# RecyclerView in fragment through activity get position

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, restore

so here is my problem, i have only one activity from i launch my viewpager fragment, in my viewpager i have 4 fragments containing recyclerViews. Every Fragment contains item populated by data on the net, when i click into one i get a WebView Fragment, but when i click on the backbutton i lost my poisiton, cause it's recreating the whole activity.

I don't know how to not recreate the activity and get back my old position, or recreating it but not changing the item's positions and have my old position back. Here's my code. Where i should put what ?!  Some help would be very very well come. 
Thank You !!

**My Activity Class :**

```
public class LauncherActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ListFragment.OnNewSelectedInterface{

    public static final String VIEWPAGER_FRAGMENT = "view_pager";
    private ImageView mImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_launcher);

        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_launcher);
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logoImageView);

        mImageView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_indefinitely));

        if(!isNetworkAvailable()){

            alertUserAboutError();

        } else {
            relativeLayout.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    ViewPagerFragment savedFragment = (ViewPagerFragment)
                            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(VIEWPAGER_FRAGMENT);

                    if(savedFragment == null) {
                        ViewPagerFragment viewPagerFragment = new ViewPagerFragment();
                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.activity_launcher, viewPagerFragment, VIEWPAGER_FRAGMENT);
                        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    }
                }
            }, 2000);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onListNewSelected(int index, ArrayList<Articles> articles) {
        WebViewFragment webViewFragment = new WebViewFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt(ViewPagerFragment.KEY_NEW_INDEX, index);
        bundle.putParcelableArrayList(ListFragment.KEY_LIST, articles);
        webViewFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.activity_launcher, webViewFragment, WebViewFragment.WEBVIEWFRAGMENT);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager)
                getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isAvailable = false;
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            isAvailable = true;
        }
        return isAvailable;
    }

    private void alertUserAboutError() {
        AlertDialogFragment alertDialogFragment = new AlertDialogFragment();
        alertDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "error_dialog");
    }

}
```

**My ViewPagerClass :**

```
public class ViewPagerFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String KEY_NEW_INDEX = "key_new_index";
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private TabLayout mTabLayout;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_pager, container, false);

        final OldFactFragment oldFactFragment = new OldFactFragment();

        final SportFragment sportFragment = new SportFragment();

        final BuzzFragment buzzFragment = new BuzzFragment();

        final NewsFragment newsFragment = new NewsFragment();

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        mTabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);


        mViewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()) {
            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                if(position == 0){
                    return oldFactFragment;
                } else if (position == 1) {
                    return newsFragment;
                } else if (position == 2){
                    return sportFragment;
                } else return buzzFragment;
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                if(position == 0){
                    return "Pastly";
                } else if (position == 1) {
                    return "politic";
                } else if (position == 2){
                    return "sport";
                } else return "buzz";
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 4;
            }

        });

        mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        return view;
    }
}
```

**My ListFragment(Parent's class of the 4 Fragments in the ViewPager) :**

```
public abstract class ListFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String KEY_LIST = "key_list";

    public interface OnNewSelectedInterface {
        void onListNewSelected(int index, ArrayList<Articles> articles);
    }

    protected static final String TAG = ListFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    protected ArrayList<Articles> mArticlesList;
    protected ItemAdapter mArticleAdapter;
    protected RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    protected OnNewSelectedInterface mListener;
    protected RecyclerView.LayoutManager mManager;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mListener = (OnNewSelectedInterface) getActivity();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        getInfos(getUrl());
        return view;
    }

    protected abstract String[] getUrl();

    private void getInfos(String[] url) {

        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {

            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            for (int i = 0; i < getUrl().length; i++) {
                Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url[i]).build();

                client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

                        try {
                            String jsonData = response.body().string();
                            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                Log.v(TAG, jsonData);

                                getMultipleUrls(jsonData);

                                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {

                                        getCurrentArticles(mArticlesList);
                                    }
                                });
                            } else {
                                alertUserAboutError();
                            }
                        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                alertUserAboutError();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        } else{
            alertUserAboutError();
        }

    }

    private void getMultipleUrls(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
        if (mArticlesList == null) {
            mArticlesList = getArticleForecast(jsonData);
        } else {
            mArticlesList.addAll(getArticleForecast(jsonData));
        }
    }

    private void getCurrentArticles(ArrayList<Articles> articles) {

        mArticleAdapter = new ItemAdapter(getActivity(), articles, mListener);

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mArticleAdapter);
        mManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mManager);

    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().
                getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isAvailable = false;
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            isAvailable = true;
        }
        return isAvailable;
    }

    private void alertUserAboutError() {
        AlertDialogFragment alertDialogFragment = new AlertDialogFragment();
        alertDialogFragment.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "error_dialog");
    }

    private ArrayList<Articles> getArticleForecast(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject forecast = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        JSONArray articles = forecast.getJSONArray("articles");

        ArrayList<Articles> listArticles = new ArrayList<>(articles.length());

        for (int i = 0; i < articles.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonArticle = articles.getJSONObject(i);
            Articles article = new Articles();

            String urlImage = jsonArticle.getString("urlToImage");

            article.setTitle(jsonArticle.getString("title"));
            article.setDescription(jsonArticle.getString("description"));
            article.setImageView(urlImage);
            article.setArticleUrl(jsonArticle.getString("url"));

            listArticles.add(i, article);
        }

        return listArticles;
    }
}
```

**And my ItemAdapter (Adapter Class) :**

```
public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ArticleViewHolder> {

    private final ListFragment.OnNewSelectedInterface mListener;
    protected ArrayList<Articles> mArticlesList;
    protected Context mContext;
    private int mPosition;
    private int lastPosition = -1;


    public ItemAdapter(Context contexts, ArrayList<Articles> mArticleLi, ListFragment.OnNewSelectedInterface listener){
        mContext = contexts;
        mArticlesList = mArticleLi;
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public ArticleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item_linear, parent, false);

        view.findViewById(R.id.textView).setSelected(true);
        ArticleViewHolder articleViewHolder = new ArticleViewHolder(view);
        articleViewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);

        return articleViewHolder;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ArticleViewHolder holder, int position) {
        mPosition = position;
        holder.bindArticle(mArticlesList.get(position));
        setAnimation(holder.itemView, position);
        holder.mImageView.setClipToOutline(true);


    }

    private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position) {
        if (position > lastPosition) {
            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(viewToAnimate.getContext(), android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
            viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);
            lastPosition = position;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mArticlesList.size();
    }

    public class ArticleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener{

        private TextView mTitle, mArticle;
        private ImageView mImageView;

        private ArticleViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            mArticle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.showTextView);
            mImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        }

        private void bindArticle(Articles article) {

            mTitle.setText(article.getTitle());
            mArticle.setText(article.getDescription());
            mArticle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Glide.with(mContext).load(article.getImageView()).into(mImageView);
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mListener.onListNewSelected(getLayoutPosition(), mArticlesList);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

            String desc = mArticlesList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getDescription();
            mArticle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mArticle.setText(desc);
            mArticle.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mArticle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }, 3000);
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to in 'onListNewSelected' to add the fragment instead to replace it

Comment: No i didn't I'll try that and tell you. Thx

Comment: Damn, i tried so many things, it was just that.. Thank's a lot. Can you explain me why replace does'nt work but it works with add ? Please !

Comment: I have added an answer explaining this part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your method `onListNewSelected` You are Replacing the new *fragment* with the old one as stated in this line

`fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.activity_launcher, webViewFragment, WebViewFragment.WEBVIEWFRAGMENT);`

From [Google Documentaion](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace(int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String))

> Replace an existing fragment that was added to a container. This is essentially the same as calling remove(Fragment) for all currently added fragments that were added with the same containerViewId and then add(int, Fragment, String) with the same arguments given here.

So you are removing the old *Fragment* then adding the new one, When you are back to get the old *fragment*, It is not already there it will be created from scratch, So the position is already gone with the removed *fragment*.

While using the `add` method, Will add the new *fragment* above the previous one, when you go back the previous one already there with its state "Position"